# Why did Jeremiah Gottwald use his Geass on Nunnally?

Tags: code-geass

In Code Geass R2, on episode 49, when Lelouch went to Nunnally

> who was the holding F.L.E.I.J.A. switch, to confront her and to give to him the switch, it was revealed that she has now regained her sight which she lost because of his father, Charles Vi Britannia's geass. The only existing geass who can possibly cancel out that geass was the Geass Canceller. And Jeremiah Gottwald has that geass. On the previous episode, Nunally has fallen from her wheelchair and someone helped her. So it can be assumed (though it was not really stated or shown) that Jeremiah was the one who helped her then and canceled out the geass Charles used on her, thus having her regain her sight again.

My question is, why would Jeremiah

> use his geass on Nunnally? (Assuming that he really was the reason why Nunnally regained her sight again.)

Was it out of pity? Since he

> has vowed his loyalty to Lelouch,

did he feel the need to help Lelouch's sister, knowing that she is very important to him?

Or was it included in Lelouch's plan? If it is, what will it gain him?

Or Lelouch purposely asked Jeremiah to do it for him, again, for his sister's sake?

Or it was just a random act for Jeremiah just for the purpose of having his geass used?

I just need some clarifications on this part. Maybe I overlooked something or misunderstood something, but any clarifications would do. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He didn´t use Geass Canceller on her because they have never even met. regardless of that, how would he cancel her if she had no eyesight?

Either she overcame the Geass by her own or all Charles´s Geass are canceled upon his death.

Comment: Great point! :) But then, who was the one who helped her when she fell from her wheelchair? She hasn't gain her eyesight then but when Lelouch came, she already had.

Comment: Furthermore, he defeated his father long ago. So if Charles' death was the cause of Nunnally's regaining of sight, then she should have regained that long before. Remember, on episode 46, Lelouch defeated his father, then the next scene was one month later, when Lelouch declared himself as the new Emperor of Britannia (or, will it take that long before a geass can be cancelled?). Was it explained that cast Geass can be cancelled after the Geass who cast it died? And was there a situation where someone did overcome the Geass that was cast on him/her?

Comment: Nunally could´ve simply been hiding that she regained her eyesight. And no one helped her get back up from the wheelchair because when he finally came back for her, it was to use her as a prisoner.

Comment: @ChristianAurigFrøkjær Well they did say :  When Lelouch comes to retrieve the F.L.E.I.J.A. control key from Nunnally, she reveals that she somehow managed to overcome her blindness, caused by the effects of their father's Geass, *through her own willpower*

Comment: according to the wiki, the geass canceller will automatically reverse any Geass used on Jeremiah or anybody else in its range. So it could have been possible for Jeremiah to use it on Nunnally

Comment: Jeremiah still wasn´t within range at any point until the grand finale.

Comment: **Nunnally was helped back on her chair:** Lelouch had always planned to destroy Damocles and of cause Nunnally was on board, even on opposite sides Lelouch still loved Nunnally, Lelouch would have had an agent ensure that no matter what happened to him or the Zero Requiem Nunnally would be safe so that he wouldn't loose her like he almost did last time

Comment: **Jeremiah being on Damocles:** as ChristianAurigFrøkjær has said, Jeremiah wasn't in range, he was fighting C.C with the Siegfried and was in the ocean with her at the end after she was defeated

Comment: **Geass is canceled when the user dies:** this can be tied with the debate of if Lelouch is dead or not as there are conflicting evidence, the girl Lelouch commanded to scratch the wall everyday had stopped and the Geass Canceler was never use in Ashford (however she could have been in town in the same area as Shirley unconfirmed thuough), what contradicts this is Schnizel's order to "Obey Zero" which he is doing at the ever end (and since Zero is now Suzaku Schnizel would obey him) so that either means Lelouch is alive of Geass doesn't disappear when the user dies

Comment: @Memor-X Geass is NOT CANCELLED upon user's death. Charles was long dead (months) during the Damocles battle, and Nunnaly was still blind, as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nunnally_Lamperouge . Geass can be weakened by the user's death, but not broken.

Comment: @ChristianAurigFrøkjær Area effect geass do not need eye contact. Rolo Lamperouge, Mao, Bismark, all these guy's geass work without eye contact.

Comment: @Mindwin if you read my entire comment i also explain a contradiction about Geass being canceled or even weakening after the caster's death. If Lelouch did die then the Geass on Schnizel should be weakening however according to the [Code Geass Wiki](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Schneizel_el_Britannia) and what we see at the end he is still "obeying Zero", if the Geass had weakened he would not be given his character, however as i also noted, this contradiction will be cleared out once we get a definitive comment from the writers about Lelouch's fate

Comment: @Memor-X we do have a canon position on Lelouch's fate: UNKNOWN. The show producers decided to cut the shot of the cart rider smiling, to leave interpretation OPEN (craps the people like me that need certainty, but caters to a larger audience) to generate specifically this kind of buzz we have right now on if he lives or dies. Even worse, is geass cancelled upon the user receiving a code? lolz. PS: the wikia sites info is not the best source for stuff. lots and lots of speculation in disguise everywhere (not only code geass site, mind you).

Comment: @xjshiya I think she climbed her wheelchair by herself. Disabled people have extraordinary arm coordination and strength for their frames (compared to regular people) and If you think that she has been for years in that state, it is safe to assume she climbed her wheelchair on her own from the ground at least a couple times way before boarding the Damocles.

Answer (score 3):

He did not, as he was fighting elsewhere far beyond the range. Nunnaly broke the geass out of sheer willpower. Some individuals can resist part of a geass, or overcome it.

It is shown for example, that Susaku can retain the memories of what he does under the influence of the Geass, while everyone else forgets.

Think of how she was feeling when it happened. She had reason to believe that not finding the key would be the defeat of her side, and everything she held dear.

That would be enough to break the geass on her eyes. Note that it is not shown that it also break the geass about her fake memories implanted during her mother's death.

Also, EVEN if you think Orange-kun could make a dispell bubble that large (kilometers), it would also dispell the geass on Lelouch soldiers. So he only used it to dispel (presumed) Charle's (or Marianne's) geass on Anya, after he opens up her cockpit during the battle.

(I think its not shown he used it after the Mall incident).

Answer (score 0):

## It's simple, he didn't.

#### First off, he couldn't use his Geass Canceller even if he wanted to:

At the moment, he was fighting Anya in Mordred and even fter he defeated her, his Knightmare (both parts) was already destroyed and also even if Mordred wasn't damaged enough, he would have to get access code from Anya to pilot it. Moreover, Damocles's shields were still up at that time, so he couldn't even get inside the shield, since the temporary hole that Lelouch created was already gone.

#### Secondly, it's been several cases of people resisting Geass and even breaking it without the Geass Canceller.

Namely, Lelouch himself (though with the help of C.C.'s kiss) did break the same Charles's Geass and restored his memory. Suzaku is known to partially resist Lelouch's Geass order due to his willpower to get an upper hand in combat. Euphemia was resisting Lelouch's order for some time because she didn't want to kill the Japanese and seemed to break out of that order before dying as she couldn't put herself to hurt Suzaku. The same Nunnaly did also resist Lelouch's order to give him the Damocles key. So it's not unnatural to be able to resist Geass without Geass Canceller.

#### Lastly, it's been stated in-universe by Lelouch, that she did overpower Charles's Geass by herself.

After Nunnally opens her eyes Lelouch literally says that she did break Geass on her own.

Also, Jeremiah didn't just vouch for his loyalty to Lelouch. His loyalty to Lelouch originates from his loyalty to Marianne and Nunnally is also her child. Also from [his fandom wiki profile](https://codegeass.fandom.com/wiki/Jeremiah_Gottwald):

> His loyalty towards Marianne, and to an extent, to Lelouch and Nunnally, was so devoted that he is willing to betray anyone in order to prove his loyalty to them.

Moreover, while going to the battle, Jeremiah says

> For Lelouch, for Nunnally

which shows his loyalty to both of them.